# A generic error has occurred in GDI+

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gdi+

I know this has been asked a million times but I think I need to make it a million and one.

I am getting `"A generic error has occurred in GDI+"` when trying to save a new `bitmap`.

I have completely stripped down to the most basic lines of code and I still get the error with the following method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return this.View();
  }

  public void CreatePicture()
  {
    try
    {    
      // THIS WORKS
      System.IO.File.Copy("C:\\copyTest.bmp", "C:\\test folder\\copyTest2.bmp");

      // THIS WORKS
      System.IO.File.Delete("C:\\test folder\\deleteTest.bmp");

      using (Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(120, 120))
      {
        // THIS FAILS
        newBitmap.Save("C:\\test folder\\test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
      throw ex;
    }
  }
}
```

The code is called from an html link on a blank page within an `MVC 3.0` website using anonymous login.

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Picture", "CreatePicture", "Home", new { })
```

I have checked the folder permissions of "test folder" and have given full access to the following:

- ASPNET
- NETWORK SERVICE
- IUSR

I still get the error...  what have I missed / done wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide some more code?

Comment: I've added more to the question post.  It's a new blank mvc project so there isn't much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem after over 4 hours.

My computer started grinding itself to a halt so I decided to restart it.

After reboot (no updates installed by the way) magically everything is now working!!!

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by another reason but in this case it seems you haven't specified image type.
So try : `newBitmap.Save("C:\\test folder\\test.bmp",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp );`